# What is the purpose of "done" in q promise chains?

Tags: javascript, q

What is the purpose of using `done` in `Q` promise chains. IIUC it propogates the error. If so, how can I catch said error?

The following code outputs: `Uncaught Error: hello world`. How can I catch this error? Do I *have* to use the `.catch` syntax, or is there another way?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/q.js/0.9.2/q.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
<script>
try {
        var foo = {
          bar: function() {
            var d = Q.defer();
            d.resolve();
            return  d.promise;
          }
        };

        function bam() {
          throw new Error('hello world');
        }

        foo.bar().then(bam).done(); // what is the purpose of done?
} catch (e) {
    alert(e);
}
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a doc comment in the source says:

> Terminates a chain of promises, forcing rejections to be thrown as exceptions.

https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/v1/q.js#L1768

Comment: https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promisedoneonfulfilled-onrejected-onprogress

i.e. The Golden Rule of done vs. then usage is: either return your promise to someone else, or if the chain ends with you, call done to terminate it. Terminating with catch is not sufficient because the catch handler may itself throw an error.